# how to get the cursor in UITextView without keyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, user-interface, keyboard

I am developing a program in which I have `UITextView` in that I need a cursor without the key board.In this cursor is show only with the keyboard if I hide the keyboard cursor will also get hide.How can I get the cursor without the key board ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cursor is displayed as long as you `UITextView` is being edited.
Thus, you can change its `inputView` view to some other view if you need to, and it will be displayed instead of the keyboard.

See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html

With this method you can add your custom inputView, a UIPickerView for example, or as you say you want you can add a minimalist hidden UIView.

If you want to restrict UITextField content, you still need to implement UITextFieldDelegate, as the user can still paste content to your text field!